# If $ \text{NV}_{\text{TM}}$ is decidable, then $A_{TM}$ is decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

It seems that $ \text{NV}_{\text{TM}} = \{〈N〉: N \text{ a Turing-Machine and } L(N) ≠ ∅\}$ is not decidable.

Here is a proof:

> Suppose that $\text{NV}_{\text{TM}}$ is decidable with the
> Turing-Machine $R$.
>
> We can define for each Turing-Machine $M$ and each entry $w$ a
> Turing-Machine $S_{M,w}$ as follow:
>
> $S_{M,w} :=$
>
> 1. If $x \not= 0$, then reject $x$;
> 2. If $x = 0$, then simulate $M$ on $w$ and accept if and only if $M$ accepts $w$
>
> Consider now the Turing-Machine
>
> $T :=$
>
> 1. Input $〈M,    w〉$:
> 2. Construct the machine $S_{M,w}$ and product $〈S_{M,w}〉$;
> 3. Simulate $R$ on the input $〈S_{M,w}〉$ :
> 4. If $R$ accepts $〈S_{M,w}〉$ then accept $〈M,   w〉$
> 5. If $R$ rejects $〈S_{M,w}〉$ then reject $〈M,   w〉$

I am a bit confused.

1. How it is possible to simulation $R$ on the input $〈S_{M,w}〉$
2. The proof says nothing else. Supposing that $ \text{NV}_{\text{TM}}$ decidable should implies that $A_{TM}$ is also decidable. How with that proof can we say that $A_{TM}$ is dedicable (Contradiction)?

Answer (score 0):

### For the first part

The idea behind the proof is to assume towards contradiction that it is decidable. Then, there must be that turing machine $R$. Its a real turing machine, and you can write its code if you want. Therefore, you can simulate it on any input you would like, and in particular, you can on $\langle S_{M,w}\rangle$ too.

### For the second part

Notice what $T$ does: It takes an input $\langle M, w\rangle$ and **decides** whether $w\in L(M)$ or not. That is, $T$ decides $A_{TM}$ in contradiction.

Comment: Your first part doesn't really help me. What does it mean to "Simulate $R$ on the input $〈S_{M,w}〉$". For me it is weird to simulate a Turing-Machine on another Turing-Machine.

Comment: Are you familiar with the universal turing machine? It allows us to simulate other turing machines. Think of simulating turing machines like a part of your code calling a function someone else wrote. Thats a totally legitimate thing to do

Comment: Are you up to talk UTM a bit more in a special section of your answer?

Comment: Sure, I think I can continue to discuss UTM with you in the chat (instead of in the comments here)

Comment: What chat? You will modify your answer?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123391/utm